# can't get rootscope working in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-rootscope, angular-broadcast

so im trying to broadcast a event from a controller to another.
but i keep getting this [error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$rootscopeProvider%20%3C-%20$rootscope%20%3C-%20SettingsController)

my controller look like this.

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).
   controller('20SettingsController',
     ['$rootscope','$scope', '$http', '$modal', 
     function ( $rootscope, $scope, $http, $modalInstance) 
     {
        $rootscope.broadcast("fireEvents");
     }]);
```

I Am doing something worng?

as always thanks for your time.

Comment: isn't it $rootScope with capital 'S'? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope

Comment: you kidding me. been sitting for over a hour trying to figure out whats worng. im gonna try it out. give me a sec.

Comment: Well. this removed the error i got. but now i just got a $rootScope.broadcast is not a function error

Comment: wait. forgot the $ infront of broadcast

Comment: @Jax. my problem was as you said. so throw it as a answer an i will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is just that you misspelled $rootscope,

it should be [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) with capital 'S'?

It happens :-)